# How to access mixins in functional component in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mixins

I have a following mixin:

```
Vue.mixin({
    computed: {
        $_styles() {
            return { backgroundColor: "red" }
        }
    }
})
```

Then, I have following functional component:

```
<template functional>
    <!-- $_styles doesn't work -->
    <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px;" :style="$_styles">
    </div>
</template>
```

How do I actually access global variable, in this case it's `$_styles`, inside functional component?

Comment: It's not a global variable. You might have better luck finding an answer if you search for _"vue functional component access mixin computed"_

Comment: I'm not sure why you would expect a functional component to have access to a computed property given... [_"they’re stateless (no reactive data) and instanceless (no `this` context)"_](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Functional-Components)

Comment: @Phil I mean "global" as in mixins/Vue.prototype. For example, if I do `Vue.prototype.$_styles = {backgroundColor: 'red'}`, then how should I access `$_styles`. Sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: In functional components, I can access `context` object. Is it possible somehow to alter this context object so that I can do `context.$_styles = {...}`. So something global I meant.

Comment: Sure, it's available via [`context.data.style`](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#The-Data-Object-In-Depth) but you can't use a template-based functional component in that case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this with a template-based functional component but if you define your `render` function, you can manipulate the `context.data.style` property, including pulling the mixin values from the `context.parent` component.

```js
Vue.mixin({
    computed: {
        $_styles() {
            return { backgroundColor: 'red' }
        }
    }
})

Vue.component('func-component', {
  functional: true,
  render (createElement, context) {
    const style = {
      height: '100px',
      width: '100px',
      ...context.parent.$_styles // get mixin styles from parent component
    }
    return createElement('div', {
      ...context.data,
      style // override context.data.style
    }, context.children)
  }
})

new Vue({el: '#app'})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <func-component></func-component>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution which works with some simpler mixins:

```
Vue.mixin({
    computed: {
        $_styles() {
            return { backgroundColor: 'red' }
        }
    }
})

Vue.component('func-component', {
  functional: true,
  mixins: [styles],
  stylesMixin() {
    // grab styles from mixin using this.computed.
    return this.computed._styles()
  },
  render (createElement, context) {
    ...
  }
})

new Vue({el: '#app'})
```

Now use `$options` to access the local stylesMixin function

```
<template functional>
    <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px;" :style="$options.stylesMixin()">
    </div>
</template>
```

However this will not work if your mixin is using any dependencies.

---

**EDIT:** another way is instead of the mixin computing the value in the .Vue component at render time, a factory pre-computes the value and adds that value as an object property.  It's easier to access properties in a functional component than mixins.  In your example, the ajax call would load, then the factory would process the objects, adding a _styles as a property.  Then you would access props.myProp._styles.